# To create a new apple ID on another iPhone

Tags: iphone

Now my wife is holding iPhone 5S. She can't remember even though she created Apple ID and I cloud mail. She asked me, please create an Apple ID for her on my iPhone. Because I am working on abroad. Let me know how to create an Apple ID on another iPhone.

Comment: don't create another, find out the details for the first one. Start at http://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Apple Id on [My Apple Id](https://appleid.apple.com) website. Just click on Create a New Apple Id and follow the instructions.

In that website you can also Reset your password, that maybe it's a better option.